# how to set [automatic] appropriate compiler for file type in sublime text 3

Tags: file, compilation, format, sublimetext3

Working in a project in Sublime Text 3, there are many files with several formats (py, jar, tex, etc.) When I want to run certain file (compile it), I have to change to the appropriate compiler to do it.

There is a way in Sublime Text to automatically set up the compiler according to the type of file, so it is not necessary to do it manually?

Comment: have you tried the Tools menu -> Build System -> Automatic?

Comment: @KeithHall Thank you. =)

Answer (score 1):

If you set the build system to automatic (Tools menu -> Build System -> Automatic), ST will choose which build system to use based on the syntax of the active tab.

There's a tiny bit of documentation here on it: http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#meta-options-in-build-systems